# video with transparent background not playing in IOS using AVPlayer

Tags: ios, objective-c, avplayer

i have a ".mov" video with a transparent background to add effects over my view, but when i try to play it the video loads n plays but i get a blank screen, here my code:

```
@property (nonatomic) AVPlayer *avPlayer;
@property (nonatomic) AVPlayerViewController* avPlayerView;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
NSBundle* bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
NSString* path = [bundle pathForResource:@"Spit" ofType:@"mov"];
NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];

AVAsset *asset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:fileURL options:nil];
AVPlayerItem *anItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithAsset:asset];

_avPlayer = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:anItem];
[AVPlayer addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"status" options:0 context:nil];
_avPlayerView = [[AVPlayerViewController alloc] init];
_avPlayerView.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
_avPlayerView.player = _avPlayer;

[_avPlayerView view].backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[_avPlayerView view].alpha = 0.5;//or any value you think is right

    [self.view addSubview:_avPlayerView.view]; 
}
```

If anyone has an idea, any help would be much appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

Try to add your "avPlayerView" as a child view controller:

```
[self addChildViewController:_avPlayerView];
[self.view addSubview:_avPlayerView.view];
[_avPlayerView didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

If you need it fullscreen then better to add AVPlayerViewController as presented view controller. Instead of adding as subview you just present it:

```
[self presentViewController:_ avPlayerView animated:NO completion:nil];
```

Comment: @user3411226 edited. Maybe you have some broken video?

Comment: when i play the video outside the app it works fine, so i don't think that's the problem...